# get same output as solidity SHA256 in JS

Tags: solidity, javascript, hash

Is there a js function/library which gives same output as sha256 in solidity? I am saving a hash in a mapping and can access it via cli (truffle console) and see what the hash is but I would like to send this same hash as an email. So on the frontend I need to get same hash and send it over via POST request to backend which then handles the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, `soliditySHA3` mimics Solidity's `sha3`/`keccak256`, functions, which are *not* related to SHA256.

---

`web3.utils.soliditySHA3` does what you want: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3

Comment: As I know, there's a big difference between `sha256` and `sha3`, which is actually a  Keccak-256 hash function.

Comment: You're 100% right. I have no idea why I answered this way or why the answer was accepted. :-) I'm going to edit the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a huge problem trying to do that. I've tried everything and didn't find yet a proper solution to generate a hash in nodejs that is the same from a hash generated in solidity sha256 function. However, I came across this "possible" (I will explain why in quotes later) solution:

```
    function HashUtility(bytes32 val) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 h = sha256(abi.encodePacked(val));
        return h;
    }
```

Instead of trying to generate the same hash you could use this function above in solidity to generate an equal hash from a value in nodeJs. Then, in your front-end or in truffle you would do something like this:

```js
const secret = web3.utils.asciiToHex('A');
const result = await instance.HashUtility.call(secret);
```

In the code above I'm converting the string `'A'` to hexadecimal first, which gives me `0x41` then calling the method `HashUtility` to hash it. The resulting hash is:

`0x037371bf62c8a2c23f8134fc2c7049fbe698860b888c98b955644c4b8f8f3155`.

Which I couldn't find any other sha256 function that made the same hash.
Hashing with nodejs `crypto` sha256 doesn't give the same hash in any way I tried. Maybe it is because the hash is returned in hexadecimal value and I have to convert the generated string to hexadecimal? tried that, but didn't work.

I also have to say that I'm not quite sure that using the solidity `HashUtility` function I made above is a good solution. I'm not sure, but miners can see the params you send to the function and that could be a problem, because you would be revealing a value that you don't want to.
Which means that the best solution would be a way to hash it BEFORE sending it to the contract.
I don't know why it is so painful to do it in nodeJS. In python with brownie it worked very easy. I'm still looking for a solution though, might find it soon.

Comment: The web3 pads 'A' = 0x41 to the right with 0 bytes to bytes32, something like `sha256(Buffer.from('4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'hex'))`.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.
basically just add padding to the right. I found it out  and left an example of it in this other question:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110614/sha256-works-with-string-memory-but-doesnt-work-with-bytes32/110617?noredirect=1#comment133451_110617