# sha256 works with string memory but doesn't work with bytes32

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, bytes32

The problem occurs when generating a sha256 inside contract. This works fine:

```
function SimpleHash(string memory val) public returns (bytes32) {
    bytes32 h = sha256(abi.encodePacked(val));
    return h;
}
```

the `h` value returned is correctly answered, and I checked it with this piece of code:

```
const result = await instance.SimpleHash.call('A');
console.log('function return',result);
hash = SHA256('A');
console.log('hash outside the contract', hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
```

I sent the stirng `'A'` to the contract function, and it returned:
`0x559aead08264d5795d3909718cdd05abd49572e84fe55590eef31a88a08fdffd`
Very similar to the return of the function outside the contract:
`559aead08264d5795d3909718cdd05abd49572e84fe55590eef31a88a08fdffd`
Just a single `0x` added in the beginning.

However, if I change the function to receive `bytes32` as param, like this:

```
function SimpleHash(bytes32 val) public returns (bytes32) {
   bytes32 h = sha256(abi.encodePacked(val));
   return h;
}
```

And then change my javacript code to:

```
segredo = web3.utils.toHex("A");

const result = await instance.SimpleHash.call(segredo);
console.log('function return',result);

hash = SHA256('A');
console.log('hash outside the contract', hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
```

Suddenly, the sha256 values are different.
In the case above, the hash returned from the contract now is `0x037371bf62c8a2c23f8134fc2c7049fbe698860b888c98b955644c4b8f8f3155`
And the correct hash is the same as the ones before.

**How do I get the correct hash for the string 'A' sending it as bytes32 param?** I'm sure there is something I'm mistaking when sending the param. Maybe it is related to big endian and little endian enconding? Not sure how I would change that in nodeJS thogh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the representation of the data. When you move to `bytes32` the resulting data after `abi.encodedPacked` has 32 bytes, but the data used for the hash in your code `SHA256(A)` is not 32 bytes. So you need to pad the hex representation of A with the necessary number of zeros to make it 32 bytes long, because this is what your smart contract is also doing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! I will explain how I managed to make it work in another comment

Comment: If this solved your question please accept the answer so that other people know that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaime pointed above, I had to pad the hex representation with 0's until it had 32 bytes.

I've made the following function to pad the hex string:

```
function padUntil32Bytes(string) {
    string = string.padEnd(32,'0');
    return string;
}
```

And created the hash as follows:

```
secret = web3.utils.toHex('A');
secret = padUntil32Bytes(secret)
const result = await instance.SimpleHash.call(secret);
console.log('function return',result);
hash = SHA256(secret);
console.log('hash outside the contract',hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
```

Now the hash from solidity and the hash outside, in javascript, match:

```
function return 0x94c49226434bc7945693fae7428a089ad81084ef4514c28cd9e7f6df2d05c3f5
hash outside the contract 94c49226434bc7945693fae7428a089ad81084ef4514c28cd9e7f6df2d05c3f5
```